# htaccess Options -Indexes ? on root folder not working

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "^\.git">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

hello what im trying to do is **disable all** of my folder recursively from the root **so there is no file listing**. how can i do that ? is this the right way ?

Thanks

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AllowOverride Options -Indexes
```

http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/

Comment: nope still dont work, something is missing i guess, in my localhost it work great, not on production :|

Comment: @AdamRamadhan - Sounds like your hosts have not enabled the apache modules to allow these modifications, who are you hosting with? You could use create a php file containing the `<?php phpinfo (); ?>`, upload to the server and run the file to see all info on your server config.

Comment: allow override ? or ? what module did i need to know?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html Scroll down to: AllowOverride Directive

Comment: well not sure until tomorrow but i bet you are right. thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do Options minus, so how about `Options None`?

Comment: still no clue. on my local it works fine,  but on my production its  an internal server error